# proving this algebraic expression

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

I want to prove that:

> $A^n-B^n=(A-B)(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B...+AB^{n-2}+B^{n-1})$

I checked that it holds for n=2, and n =3(not n=1). So I think maybe I can use induction? However I get stuck:

Assuming that it holds for n, I need to show that:

$A^{n+1}-B^{n+1}=(A-B)(A^n+A^{n-1}B...+AB^{n-1}+B^{n})$

Any hints?

Comment: Did you try expanding the right hand side? If so then you will see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $A^{n+1} - B^{n+1} = A^{n+1} - A^nB+A^nB -B^{n+1} = A^n(A-B) + B(A^n-B^n)$ can be used in the inductive step.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your initial equation as $$A^n-B^n=(A-B)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{n-k-1}B^k$$. Distribute to get $$A^n-B^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A \cdot A^{n-k-1}B^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{n-k-1}B\cdot B^k$$ and then reindex. The right-hand side is now $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^{n-k}B^k-\sum_{k=1}^n A^{n-k}B^k$$, which simplifies to leave $$A^{n-0}B^0-A^{n-n}B^n=A^n-B^n$$.